# How to remove "repeated" maps within a list?

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

I have the following list

```
  List<Map> testList = [
  {"coordinateId1": "smfs9f87enf3", "coordinateId2": "jsnd29829ne2"},
  {"coordinateId1": "smfs9f87enf3", "coordinateId2": "dxs39xmr398m"},
  {"coordinateId1": "jsnd29829ne2", "coordinateId2": "smfs9f87enf3"},
  {"coordinateId1": "jsnd29829ne2", "coordinateId2": "dxs39xmr398m"},
  {"coordinateId1": "dxs39xmr398m", "coordinateId2": "smfs9f87enf3"},
  {"coordinateId1": "dxs39xmr398m", "coordinateId2": "jsnd29829ne2"}];
```

In my logic, elements 0 and 2 of the list are equal, as well as 1 and 4 and 3 and 5. That is, if the coordinateId1 and coordinateId2 values ​​of an element x are equal to the coordinateId2 and coordinateId1 values, respectively, of a y element, these elements are equal.

Within this context, how do I not have repeated elements?

I've tried using for and removing it, but a runtime error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

In this function i create a unique identifier for each of the map values, that is a concatenated string of the key plus the value, then i store this in a set (that avoids repeated values), then interate through the list and check if the unique key is already in the set, if it isnt i add it to the filtered list, at the end i return the filtered list

```js
List<Map<String, String>> removeDuplicates(List<Map<String, String>> inputList) {
  Set<String> uniqueValues = {};
  List<Map<String, String>> outputList = [];

  for (Map<String, String> map in inputList) {
    String value1 = map['coordinateId1']!;
    String value2 = map['coordinateId2']!;

    String uniqueKey = '$value1-$value2';

    if (!uniqueValues.contains(uniqueKey)) {
      uniqueValues.add(uniqueKey);
      outputList.add(map);
    }
  }

  return outputList;
}
```